# ¿Antónimo de "persona curiosa", persona a la que no le gusta pensar?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, antónimos

He encontrado algunos antónimos de "persona curiosa" como "abúlico", "indolente", "indiferente" y "displicente"; pero ninguna de esas palabras parece capturar esa personalidad de la gente a la que se nota que no le gusta pensar, que no quiere escuchar cuando les explicas algo, como si les doliera pensar, y que no tienen interés en aprender.

¿Alguien conoce alguna palabra mejor que las que nombro arriba?

Un posible neologismo griego sería "noelgia" o "noélgico", de noe (pensamiento) y algia (dolor): falto de curiosidad, como si le doliera pensar.

[[fuente de raíces griegas]](http://etimologias.dechile.net/griego/?Raices)

Comment: Dependiendo del contexto podría caber `desinteresado`

Comment: O tambien `conformista`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede que no haya una palabra antinómica de `curioso` en el exacto sentido de inquisitivo, ávido de ideas y dispuesto a acometer procesos mentales (para lo cual  `desinteresado` quizás se quede corto)

La situación descripta en la pregunta para alguien así la he visto corresponderse con  la expresión de

> quien demuestra [`pereza intelectual`](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=Pereza+intelectual)

Existe también (mayormente en la literatura de la salud mental) el síntoma de la

> [abulia cognitiva](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk00mFylWSFzio35lynz7at2QP32e4w%3A1590273700851&ei=pKbJXsPLM_Ke5OUP67qGmAo&q=abulia+cognitiva&oq=abulia+cognitiva&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.12...38053.68064.0.69933.63.31.15.17.19.0.137.3437.9j22.31.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..0.43.2386.3..0j41j30i10k1j0i13k1j0i333k1j33i10k1.0.9d0-am6FfjA)

Comment: Si no es una pregunta demasiado personal, tengo curiosidad de saber cuál es tu lengua materna. Algunas de las palabras que has usado como antinómica (antónima), ideás (ideas), descripta (descrita), avido (ávido) aparecen en el diccionario pero son muy poco comunes, casi incorrectas. De todas formas, gracias por la respuesta, me ha sido útil.

Comment: De nada, me alegro que la respuesta te haya sido útil. A lo de tu pregunta, soy un hispano parlante nativo (de Argentina)

Comment: La palabra *indiferente*  es similar a *desinteresado*.